# Make Parallelogram in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

im trying to make Parallelogram in react native android but SkewX property is not working and SkewY is not working well.
when we use  `transform: [{ skewY: "-10deg" }]` it is rotating view.
And if i use this method on this  [website link](https://www.codedaily.io/tutorials/The-Shapes-of-React-Native)

this example is good but how can i use these triangle and view with Gradient like this.
[image: img1]

Please look at this also
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27649

***NOTE: iOS is working fine***

Comment: did you end up getting a decent skewX workaround for android?